# Circular referencing in Javascript reference counting

Tags: javascript

In Nicholas Zakas' book, he explains the problem of circular referencing when using reference counting for garbage collection in Javascript. He uses the following example:

```
function problem(){
    var objectA = new Object();
    var objectB = new Object();

    objectA.someOtherObject = objectB;
    objectB.anotherObject = objectA;
}
```

explaining that the two objects will never have the memory allocated to them freed since they have two references to them inside the function. I would like some clarification of how this works.

Clearly, there are two references to each object. The first object has both `objectA` and `objectB.anotherObject` pointing to it. The situation is analogous for the second object. So the reference count for each object is 2. But what happens when the function is exited? This isn't really described in the book. He says that the reference count is decremented whenever a reference to the value is overwritten with another value. I think this means:

```
function problem(){
    var objectA = new Object();
    var objectB = new Object();

    objectA.someOtherObject = objectB;
    objectB.anotherObject = objectA;
    objectA.someOtherObject = objectA; //<-- that if I were to do this, 
                                       //the reference count of the second object (B) 
                                       //would become 1, and 3 for the first object (A). 

}
```

But what happens when the function exits? As far as I understand, both `objectA` and `objectB` and their respective properties that reference each other will be destroyed, and thus, the two objects' reference counts will be decremented by 2. I don't see the "circular reference problem" that Zakas talks about. Could somebody explain what he's trying to say?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> As far as I understand, both objectA and objectB and their respective properties that reference each other will be destroyed.

No. The *local variables* `objectA` and `objectB` will be destroyed (because the function scope ends and no closures reference these variables). That means the reference counts in the objects that were referenced by the variables each get decremented by **1**.

If the object's reference count was 0, the object would get destroyed and all other things it references would get their count decremented. But the counts of the objects still are `1` each - they still reference each other -, and nothing gets destroyed.

Comment: Is there an implementation which still relies on reference counting? According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management, these objects *will be* destroyed with all modern implementations.

Comment: @rici No, reference counting - at least in its naive form - is not used exactly because of this deficiency and [needs improvements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting#Dealing_with_reference_cycles). As MDN states, all modern engines use some mark-and-sweep implementation. However, reference counting can still be applied to specific local structures known to be not or not very cyclic where it might perform better because of its simplicity.

Comment: yeah, that's what i thought. I suppose the book referred to in the OP is somewhat dated, since I believe early versions of MSIE suffered from this problem. But my impression is that modern ES implementations will correctly garbage collect both objects in this example. I understand that the question is to explain the problem with circular references in a ref-counted environment but surely it is worth mentioning in the answer that the problem no longer exists in practice; there is no need to manually break reference cycles, contrary to advice you will still find floating around.

Answer (score 11):

The "problem" with reference counting and "circular" reference comes about when allocated objects contain references to other objects, but are otherwise unreferenced by active allocations. That is, there are cliques in the overall reference graph of items that are not active but which nevertheless contain references to other non-active items.

In your example code, when that function exits there are no *active* references to the two allocated objects, but the objects reference each other so the reference counts are not 0. The local variables `objectA` and `objectB` will disappear at the exit of the function (because the closure is itself garbage, at that point), but the internal references the objects hold keep their reference counts greater than zero.

It's not an unsolvable problem, but it complicates the otherwise simple approach of reference counting as a garbage collection technique.

Note that there's no rule or specification that insists JavaScript implementations use any particular garbage collection technique.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One further question: If `objectA` and `objectB` are destroyed, how come their underlying properties aren't destroyed with them? Am I confusing the local variables (which are references?) with the actual objects in memory?

Comment: The *variables* `objectA` and `objectB` are destroyed. Think of local variables as properties of a "shadow" object created when the function is called. When the function exits, that object has no references to it so its properties go away. All that means is that the objects *referenced* by the local variables have their reference counts decremented by 1.

Comment: "there are cliques..." -- do you mean "cycles", instead? Cliques (complete subgraphs) do manifest the issue, but they are not necessary for it.

Comment: @chi well I'm not a graph theorist, but what I meant was there are "clumps" of allocations that reference each other but which aren't referenced by anything else. That's what happens after the last non-cyclic reference is cleared. If you're confident in a better term for that then let me know and I'll edit the answer.